# 405 error code on static html spring boot

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am trying to return a static html(`index.html`) page using spring boot but I am alway getting a 405 error whem I trying (http://localhost:8080/). Strange fact is that debugger enters `index()` method.

`HomeController:`

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

I have tried to return `"index.html"` and "index" strings.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext
                = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

location of html file is:
`src\main\resources\public\index.html`

here goes a part of startup logger output:

```
INFO 8284 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.acs.map.controller.HomeController.index()
```

Screanshot of an error 
[image]

and i am running project with gradle: `gradle bootRun`

Logger message after request:

```
WARN 3988 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Also I have tried with and without this configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/public/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/public/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/public/");
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(InternalResourceView.class);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using just "index" instead of "index.html". Personally, I have never needed to use the suffix. Also, why have you used backslashes in your URL? Slashes should be used.

Comment: Neither "index" and "index.html" works. Which backslashes you are talking about?

Comment: `src\main\resources\public\index.html` these ones.

Comment: I pasted it just to show were `index.html` is located. It is not url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources). I did a quick check by following the below structure and was successful. 
[image]

So I believe by extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class like below and it should return static content using your current controller code (without the WebConfig class).You can use viewResolver as well to map between view names and actual views as well by further modifying your code.

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here are my project dependencies
[image]

Comment: Nope, adding extending  `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` didn't help. Can you please show your project dependencies?

Comment: Sure ..dependencies are attached in the answer

Comment: Can you please delete your WebConfig class and try to hit first ??

Comment: I have uploaded my running code here ..https://github.com/utpal416/demo

Comment: Also, your project runs correct even when I removed `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Comment: Ok, appeated that I have had a another `@RestController("/eg")` where one method was annotated with `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)` without specifing a value, when i removed it, everything started to work.

Comment: @yurii How does this answer your question? I'm confused.

Comment: I had this same problem, and as @yurii said, it was because my controller was annotated with `@RestController("/api/v1/foo")` and my method was annotated with `@PostMapping` (no value).  When I changed to `@RestController` (no value) and `@PostMapping("/api/v1/foo")`, swagger-ui.html displayed as expected.  No need for `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.